# WPF button customTemplate background changes with HorizontalAlignement

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I have a strange behavior in my application. I defined custom buttons with controlTemplating like this

```
<Style x:Key="StandardButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3F3F46"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#54545C"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderThickness="2"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><ContentPresenter /></TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

which looks like this in the designer
[image: Button in designer]

However, when I run my application, it looks more like this
[image: Button in application]

You see the darker part around the text in the button ? I don't have this behavior when I don't specify the HorizontalAlignment property of the textbock. Is that an issue with my screen or what have I forgotten ?
Thanks !

EDIT

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Background="#FF2D2D30">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,151,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonClBck" />
     </Grid>
</Window>

<Application x:Class="OtdrQualifTools.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ControlStyles;component/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I can't see why that would make a difference. However, the `TextBlock` element is not needed: just put the `ContentPresenter` within the `Border` and set the HorizontalAlignment property on that.

Comment: Indeed, it makes no difference... but the question is still valid. I have this strange behavior I can't explain. Maybe it is due to my screen rendering ?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you get rid of the `TextBlock` element and just use a `ContentPresenter`? If not, what Content markup have you placed inside your `Button` control?

Comment: No the problem is still here, but it does not happen without HorizontalAlignment in my style, however the content is aligned to the left

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to tell without seeing the xaml that you're using the style in.  It works fine for me.  Depending on your requirements, I'm not sure I understand why you would want to wrap the content presenter in a TextBlock.  See below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StandardButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3F3F46"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#54545C"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}" Height="30" Width="100" Content="Button" />
</Grid>
```

For what it is worth... you may have a rogue style in your app.xaml that will show at runtime, but not in the designer of the main window.  something like this (I was able to recreate what you were seeing in this way):

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF343339" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Good point with the textblock style defined within another style... but it does not fix the issue as if the HorizontalAlignment is set to 'Left' I don't have this behavior

Comment: Get rid of the textblock in the template and add the horizontal alignment to the content presenter... that should accomplish what you need.  It appears you may have other styles competing against eachother.  Good luck.

Comment: As I said before, it does not fix the problem sadly ;)

Comment: At this point, I would check the app for style that is applied globally to all content presenters, borders, and textblocks... you may find some offending markup that is interfering.